# Is batch initialization of objects possible with the use of LINQ in C#.net?

Tags: c#, linq, object

I have this object of mine named Rooms can i batch initialized them using linq instead of using this kind of code?

```
List<Rooms> listOfRooms = new List<Rooms>();
foreach(var room in listOfRooms)
{
  room = new Rooms();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't even make sense... Are you trying to pre-initialize the list with a certain number of Rooms?

Comment: How many `Rooms` do you need to initialize? Because this code do nothing yet.

Comment: That piece of code won't initialize any `Rooms`, because the List is empty!

Comment: Correct you code, or your question will be closed as not constructive. Code is missing significant part - `List<T>` list initialization. Default constructor initializes the list only with `List<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)` parameter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var listOfRooms = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(p => new Rooms()).ToList();
```

This is a solution for creating a `List` with 10 `Rooms`.

Note that in the `Select` you have access to the index (0...9) (called `p`). You can use to do fancy logic and initialized `Rooms` with specific values.

As suggested by Mustafin, there is an "hybrid" Linq expression that can be used:

```
var listOfRooms = (from p in Enumerable.Range(0, 10) select new Rooms()).ToList();
```

I don't like this form because it "mixes" the two "styles" of Linq.

Comment: Cleaner than using the List constructor... +1

Comment: +1 this is the way I would do it for a trivial list with default values

Comment: @Adam Technically you can do it even for non-default values. The Select method give you access to p, so you know the index and you CAN do some specific initialization (p == 0 ? something : something else)

Comment: @xanatos true - but I would probably look at NBuilder (see my answer) for doing something like that - the fluent API makes it very easy to write

Comment: var listOfRoooms = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10) select new Rooms();

Comment: @ArturMustafin I have to admit, I wasn't ever good with the from select notation of linq. And considering the equivalent of what I've written would be `(from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10) select new Rooms()).ToList()`, so mixing the two notations, I'm not sure it would be clearer.

Comment: this really helped me a lot to understand Linq. thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

To pre-initialize the list with three rooms a quick and dirty way could be:

```
List<Rooms> listOfRooms = new List<Rooms>
{
    new Rooms(),
    new Rooms(),
    new Rooms(),
}
```

Or to create 20:

```
List<Rooms> listOfRooms = 
    new List<Rooms>(Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select(ix=>new Rooms()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/).

```
var listofRooms = Builder<Rooms>.CreateListOfSize(10).Build();
```

You can also use the fluent API for, amongst other things, assigning certain values to given ranges of the list.

Comment: +1 But I'm not sure I would add another dependancy to a project only for this gimmicky. For unit testing (the main target of the library) probably yes.

Answer (score 1):

You must have one of two things to answer this question: either a known number of rooms to create or an existing enumerable that you want to create rooms for on a one-to-one basis.

Here are the two options:

```
List<Rooms> listOfRooms =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, knownNumber)
        .Select(n => new Rooms())
        .ToList();
```

and:

```
List<Rooms> listOfRooms =
    existingEnumerable
        .Select(n => new Rooms())
        .ToList();
```

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Introduction to LINQ queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/bb397906%28VS.100%29.aspx)

As you whould expect, this is a "native" compact Linq syntax:

```
var listOfRoooms = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10) select new Rooms();
```

As long as there is only tree parts of a query operation:

1. Obtain the data source.
2. Create the query.
3. Execute the query.

Your code is missing significant part - List list initialization ("Obtain the data source"). Default constructor can initialize the list with `IEnumerable<T>` constructor parameter.

```
List<Rooms> listOfRooms = new List<Rooms>();
foreach(var room in listOfRooms)
{
  room = new Rooms();
}
```

I will show you a ways to initialize list and select from this list using LINQ syntax:

Initialization:

```
List<Rooms> listOfRooms = new List<Rooms>(new Rooms[] 
{
    new Rooms(),
    new Rooms(),
    new Rooms()
});
```

Select:

```
foreach(var room in listOfRooms)
{
    if (room != null)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

or

```
 var list = from r in listOfRooms select r != null;
```